# simple javascript variable issue in js+iim code

Tags: javascript, imacros

```js
var variable=1;

var sample="CODE:";
sample += "URL GOTO="+variable;

for(i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
 iimPlay(sample);
 variable++;
}
```

I'm making a bot using javascript+imacros *(the code below is just a sample to understand the issue)*, and I need the variable to be increased by 1 for every loop. Any help?

Comment: `variable` is increased, but you do not reassign `sample` afterwards ...

Comment: Your code is also falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (you want to declare `i`, to prevent it being a global).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the variable value was not incremented inside your loop and all your loop see is the global level scope variable which contains a value of one.

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrated the output: https://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/sv2bc7Lm/

```
//initialize variable
var variable = 1;


//changed i = 0 to var i = 0 to prevent making i a global variable
for(var i  = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){//begin for loop

//append the URL GOTO assignment with the incremented variable
sample = "CODE:URL GOTO="+ variable++;           

        iimPlay(sample);


}//end for loop
```

Comment: this wont change anything. still within sample just the first value of `variable` is used.

Comment: You are right I am doing some more testing I will be right back.

Comment: Not a problem, I'm glad I could help